# $watch does not fire in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller, I set a variable to be true with `ng-click`.

In my directive, I need to evaluate something when the variable is true. Subsequently, I set the variable to be false through my directive.

However my problem is that I cannot seem to get the `$watch` to fire from the `ng-click` function.

I've included a sample fiddle of my problem. As you can see, `$watch` initially logs `true` in the console on loading the page. When I click the directive to make it `false`, `$watch` also fires and logs `false`. However subsequent clicks to the button with `ng-click` do not result in `$watch` firing. Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zcouyvwc/2/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope,$timeout) {

    $scope.boolean = true;

    $scope.setToTrue = function() {
        $timeout(function(){$scope.boolean = true;});
    };
}


app.directive("someDirective",['$timeout',function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict:"A",
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch("boolean", function() {
         console.log(scope.boolean);
        });

        element.bind('click',function(){
            $timeout(function(){
                scope.boolean = false;
            });

        });
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `someDirective` is creating a child scope, and when it sets `scope.boolean = false`, it actually creates a variable that shadows the original, so the original is unchanged

The standard advice, as from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes , is

> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models

If you change your code so that you have

```
$scope.model = {
    boolean: true
};
```

As in http://jsfiddle.net/9j87njvt/1/ , then I think it will behave as expected.

---

As a sidebar, I usually only create directives that depend on scope inheritance in this way if alternatives are more complicated or have some other disadvantage. Usually I pass in options via attributes, and use `scope: {...}` in the directive definition for an isolated scope, which keeps things more separate. Also, I'm not sure why you have `$timeout`s in a few places. You might be looking to use `scope.$apply()` in order for Angular to run the digest cycle to notice changes in the model.

Comment: aaaaahhhhhhhhh I had this problem before and I corrected it then after hours of research. I didn't realize it was the same problem again..... dohh! Thanks for noticing this!

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of prototypical scope inheritance. You see, specifying `scope:true` means that the directive creates a new scope that prototypically inherits the parent scope (that of the controller). (Search for Javascript prototypical inheritance if you are not familiar with the concept.)

Take a small break and specify `scope:false`, meaning the directive uses the parent scope. Your fiddle works. So, if you have no specific reason to have a child scope, you are done.

If not, read on: The characteristic with prototypical scope inheritance is that top level properties (i.e. `$scope.something` - in contrast to `$scope.something.deeper` → `something` is top level, `deeper` is not) get read from the first scope in hierarchy that contains them, but get written always to the current scope. At the beginning, the scope hierarchy is:

```
controller scope (contains "boolean" top level prop, value: true)
|
+- directive child scope (contains nothing)
```

After clicking the situation becomes:

```
controller scope (contains "boolean" top level prop, value: true)
|
+- directive child scope (contains "boolean" top level prop, value: false)
```

The watch is placed on the directive scope, so reads the `boolean` property from the child scope; in which case it is always `false` and the watch never triggers.

The answer is to use non-top-level properties. Place `boolean` under an object in the controller scope, i.e. `$scope.data.boolean = true` and similarily adapt the directive:

```
scope.$watch("data.boolean", function() { ... });

element.bind('click',function(){
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.data.boolean = false;
    ...
```

While you're at it, give `boolean` a better name! (see answer from developer10)

And use `$scope.$apply` like above instead of `$timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `boolean` is a reserved word in many (all) programming languages and as such may not be used for naming purposes.

[Reserved names](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

First try giving another, meaningful name to your variable and then update us if it still doesn't work.